# Hochdeutsch and pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I have been learning German for the last couple of years using DuoLingo. The dialect taught there is of course Hochdeutsch. I have since finished all DuoLingo content and have now moved on to LingQ. My question is this:
Is there a website or utility that I could use to check pronunciation of German words as I get exposed to  new words while reading and learning?
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dict.leo.org/german-english/pronunciation

has German spelling and pronunciation, directly grouped with the English translation.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at

> [de.wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite)

as it gives you pronunciations by native speakers and the IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) symbols for most of the words in it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are indeed looking for only the pronunciation of single words or simple expressions, you may use the soundbits given by the Dict.cc dictionary

https://www.dict.cc/?s=Aussprache

Click on the loudspeaker icon next to the word, and you get a collection of pronunciations by native speakers.